# Having trouble rendering an array of images from an api (Django Rest Framework) response in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, api, django-rest-framework

Hi this is my first project in both React and Django Rest Framework and I need to figure this out to complete the project.
The issue I'm having (I believe it's a React one) is that my api is returning an json response which React receives using axios which works fine since when I do the console log all the data is there and Im also able to pass the data to a tag,

etc. I would like to display the photos that are being sent to by the api. The link is not the problem as I am able to view the photo in the browser using the link provided by the api. The problem is that I have multiple images in the api response that are set up as an array.
As shown here:
[postmanResponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqvC5.png)

Response using console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NaPd.png)

I guess essentially what I'm asking is there a way that I can make an array/object with the image array that my api is delivering so that I can then use it to show the picture in React?
Any help will be helpful. Thank you!

Here is my code for the React side:

```
// Import Files
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// Import Axios
import axios from "axios";
// Import Is Mobile 
import { isMobile } from 'react-device-detect';
// Import Css
import "./projectDetail.css";
// Mobile Css
import "./projectDetailM.css"
// Lightbox
import { SRLWrapper } from "simple-react-lightbox";
// Import Footer
import Footer from "../Footer/footer"


// Project Detail Class
class ProjectDetail extends Component {



// States 
state = {
    data: [],
    photoIndex: 0,
    isOpen: false,
}

// Mount Data to the State 
componentDidMount() {
    this.handleFetchItem();
}


// Get the project via axios
handleFetchItem = () => {
    // Variables
    const {
        match: { params }
    } = this.props
    // Set State
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    // Axios Setup
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/projects/' + params.ID)
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({ data: res.data, loading: false });
        })
        .catch(console.error());
}

    // Render the page 
    render() {

        // Const 
        const { data } = this.state;
        const project = data;
        // Print to console (Debugging)
        //console.log(data);
        // Return Page
        return (
            <div className="projectDetailMainContainer">
                <div className="projectDetailGrid">
                    <div className="projectDetailArea">
                        <div className="projectNameArea">
                            <h1 className="projectNameStyling">
                                {project.title}
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div className="projectAddress1Area">
                            <h2 className="projectAddress1Styling">
                                {project.address},
                                    </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div className="projectAddress2Area">
                            <h2 className="projectAddress2Styling">
                                {project.address2}
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div className="projectCityArea">
                            <h2 className="projectCityStyling">
                                {project.city} {project.zipcode}
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div className="projectProgressArea">
                            <h3 className="projectProgressStyling">
                                {project.completed}
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div className="projectReturnButton">
                            <button
                                className="btnStyleDetailPage"
                                type="button"
                                onClick={() => { this.props.history.replace('/projects') }}>
                                Return to Project List
                                    </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="projectDetailImageArea">
                        <SRLWrapper>
                            <img className="projectImageStyling"
                                src={require("./placeholders/city.jpg")} alt={project.title} />
                        </SRLWrapper>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}


// Export Compoenent
export default ProjectDetail;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by implementing a image carousel or iterating over the images array.

First of all you must guarantee that the pictures are properly set on a state (does not matter what type of component). Then, here is one way to show all of the images and solve the problem:

```js
function ImageList(props) {  
  return (
    props.images.map((pic, index) => {
      return (
        <img key={index} src={pic.src} alt="image" />
      );
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: For some reason no matter how I try to make the code work using the snippet you gave me (I tried to modify it to make it work) I keep getting a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". I also confirmed that the states were set before I introduced the code. I have also tried to pass the function with my state in this case project in the carousel element that i have --> <SrlWrapper elements={this.ImageList(project)} /> and also as <Srl>{this.ImageList(project)</Srl> any idea on what is causing this error ( I have tried looking at other stack overflow problems and I have no luck)? TY

Comment: You must implement this component and pass to it the image list as an component property, like this: <ImageList images={myListOfImages} />

Answer (score 0):

use map like this

```
 { data.map(project => { <div className="projectDetailMainContainer">
                <div className="projectDetailGrid">
                    <div className="projectDetailArea">
                        <div className="projectNameArea">
                            <h1 className="projectNameStyling">
                                {project.title}
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div className="projectAddress1Area">
                            <h2 className="projectAddress1Styling">
                                {project.address},
                                    </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div className="projectAddress2Area">
                            <h2 className="projectAddress2Styling">
                                {project.address2}
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div className="projectCityArea">
                            <h2 className="projectCityStyling">
                                {project.city} {project.zipcode}
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div className="projectProgressArea">
                            <h3 className="projectProgressStyling">
                                {project.completed}
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div className="projectReturnButton">
                            <button
                                className="btnStyleDetailPage"
                                type="button"
                                onClick={() => { this.props.history.replace('/projects') }}>
                                Return to Project List
                                    </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="projectDetailImageArea">
                        <SRLWrapper>
                            <img className="projectImageStyling"
                                src={require("./placeholders/city.jpg")} 
                                alt={project.title} />
                        </SRLWrapper>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
})}
```

for the images you can access them by index like this

```
{project.images[0].src}
{project.images[1].src}
{project.images[2].src}
```

example:

```
<img src={project.images[0].src} alt="image" />
```